# One partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Where can I find information about equation

$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}-\operatorname{div}\left(A(x)\nabla u(x,t)\right)=f(x,t),\text{where } A(x) \text{ is a matrix 2x2}  ?$$ I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: This is diffusion equation in the divergence form.

Comment: @Paul:i think this book will help you 
Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction  walter A. strauss

Comment: Thanks,I'll look.I was confused,because in my case $A(x)$ is a matrix $2x2$, but not just a function. If it was a function, than it would be diffusion equation in the divergence form. But when there is a matrix, it won't be so, am I right?

Comment: This would only be a diffusion equation if A satisfies ellipticity conditions (that is to say, A is positive definite). Otherwise, it would be quite easy to pull other types of equations out of it.

Comment: @Paul Like Ray Yang said, this is still a diffusion equation in divergence form even when $A$ is a matrix (positive definite).

Comment: Now I see it.But will then diffusion equation look as something like $$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}(1-a'_{12}(x))-\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x \partial t}(a_{12}(x)+a_{21}(x))-a_{11}(x)\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2}-a_{22}(x)\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial t^2}-a'_{21}(x)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}=f(x,t)?$$ Here I've expanded brackets

Comment: @Paul Divergence is normally only acting on the spacial variable $x$. could you please provide some contexts like where did you see this equation?

Comment: My lector has given me this equation as an additional task, so I even have any idea, where it can be seen.
Moreover, I didn't know what to do with divergence, when it is taken from a variable with both time and spacial coordinates.

Comment: @Paul Additional task of? I suggest you go directly asking him what all these notation means.